# Use a Not in for insert in Marketing Cloud Sql Query

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio

I need to add only unique rows to a data extension even though the same row in source data extension might keep being pulled.  In Automation studio if the same primary key is pulled it errors the whole job and I get an error when I try to use Not in with the Append action.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing your query and fitting inside the requirements of your question, the best solution I can offer would be to change the 'Update method' in the Query definition screen to "Update" instead of "Append".

I know this sounds crazy as in most places, Update means, literally, "update only" - but in SFMC Queries it means "add and update".  See below snippet from their [official documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_create_a_query_activity.htm&type=5):

> - Overwrite - Delete the data extension's records and add the query results.
> - Update - Updates records in the data extension with query results and appends non-matching records.
> - Append - Adds the query results to the data extension after existing records.

There are other SQL solutions, but without seeing your code, the best I can do is point you towards some good resources:

[@AdamSpriggs blog - Sprignaturemoves](https://sprignaturemoves.com/category/salesforce-marketing-cloud/queries/)
[SFMC Sample Queries](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_sample_queries.htm&type=5)
[W3 Schools SQL](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp) (Please note not all of this works in SFMC)

Comment: That worked! The description for Update is so misleading in the system - Thanks!

Comment: If this solved your problem, please make sure to hit the check mark next to my answer to mark it as solved - this will help any others having the same issue to know this was the correct solution.